# Calculating the time light needs to reach a fast moving object

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity

I'm wondering if someone could explain me this with more details:

Assume a spaceship flies on the x-axis away from earth with $v=0.8c$. Lets call its frame $S'$. The frame of earth is called $S$.

When the spaceship is located at $x_s=6.66\cdot 10^9$ km away from earth (measured in $S$), we send him a light signal.

How long does it need, until it reaches him?

The solution says: Becuase the signal moves with c, we get:

$\Delta t_{signal}\cdot c = x_s + \Delta t_{signla}\beta c$ (1)

so

$\Delta t_{signal}=\frac{x_s}{(1-\beta)c}$

But how exactly come they up with (1)?

Edit: I do see that it actually makes sense, but still. A more detailed way to get there would be nice. Even if it's a basic problem.

Comment: You compare velocities from your rest frame. No transition between frames here and $c$ is always $c$

Comment: $\beta c=v$ ,after that it is really very simple problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing specific to relativity in the answer.  It's just kinematics in the $S$ frame.  So imagine a similar situation at lower speed: you have two runners, the slower one gets a head start.  At $t = 0$, the slower one is at $x = x_s$, the faster one at $x = 0$.  The faster one's $x$ position as a function of time: $v_{faster} t$.  The slower one's: $x_s + vt$.  You want to know at what time they're at the same position, so set them equal and solve for $t$.